# Do lambda functions have security groups by default? Can and should they be changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway and lambda functions, the lambda functions can only be accessed through the API gateway (functions are using lambda proxy integration) meaning I could restrict inbound and outbound traffic to just the API gateway

My questions are:

1. What security group are lambda functions assigned if they are not in a VPC?
2. Is it best practice to restrict that security group or use a custom one?
3. How can I alter the security group of a lambda function?
4. Is any alteration required for lambda function that don't have individual function endpoints?

I tried searching it but I didn't find anything useful about default security groups, I looked through the settings for the lambda function but didn't find anything

Answer (score 3):

Lambda functions do not have security groups by default. Lambda functions are not deployed into a VPC by default, and security groups are a function of VPCs. You can only assign a security group to a Lambda function after configuring it to be deployed into a VPC.

Security groups for Lambda functions can only restrict outbound connections. Lambda functions never have an inbound network connection. Lambda functions don't have an open network port listening for inbound network traffic. Lambda function instances don't exist until they are invoked. When a Lambda function is invoked AWS creates an instance of the function, and passes the incoming request data (not the networking connection) as a parameter to the handler function.

The most common use for Lambda function security groups are simply to assign an empty security group to them that can be referenced by other security groups. For example to allow a Lambda function to access an RDS database running in the same VPC, you would create an inbound rule in the RDS security group that allows connections from the Lambda function's security group.

> meaning I could restrict inbound and outbound traffic to just the API gateway

You restrict access to Lambda functions via the Lambda function's [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html). To restrict it so that your API Gateway can call it, you would assign a resource policy to the function that only allows your API Gateway resource to invoke it.

Your Lambda function can only ever return a response to the thing that invoked it. However, by default a Lambda function can access the Internet to do things like making API calls, connecting to public databases, S3 buckets, etc. If you want to restrict your Lambda function from making that sort of outgoing network request then you would need to place it in a VPC, however since you are in control of the source code that comprises the Lambda function, you could also just not add any code to the function that makes outgoing requests you want to avoid.