# How to see client's ipv4 address from AWS Lambda Function URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda function that exposes a public, unauthenticated Lambda Function URL. How can I see the client's ipv4 address?

In particular, I am testing from my house, where my ISP provides by an ipv4 and ipv6 address. When I go to [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com) I see

> My Public IPv4: 50.68.XXX.XXX

> My Public IPv6: 2604:3d08:5a77:7300:60e9:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx

So I think it should be possible for my lambda function to be able to read both the ipv4 and ipv6 address (since whatismyip.com is able to do it)

I tried to figure it out by creating the following python lambda function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        # dump whole event to see if the ipv4 address is there
        'body': event 
    }
```

When I visit the function URL, I get back the whole event, which does include my ipv6 address in both:

- *event['headers']["x-forwarded-for"]* and
- *event['requestContext']['http']['sourceIp']*

But I don't see the ipv4 address.

Comment: I would think that your client simply made one GET request, and that was over IPv6.

Comment: When you visit whatismyip, your browser is sending multiple HTTP requests, some over IPv4 and some over IPv6, hence the whatismyip server(s) can determine both your IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and return them in its responses to the web page requests, and hence the web page can show both addresses.

Comment: `www.whatismyip.com` has two endpoints the page checks with Javascript, `api.whatismyip.com` and `apiv6.whatismyip.com`, available only via IPv4 and IPv6 respectively to get both IP addresses (and notably, it introduces a race condition that can occur if load the page during a network change).  To recreate this, you will need more than a bare lambda function URL, you'll need two end points that you can ensure expose on IPv4 or IPv6, not both.

Comment: @jarmod and @Anon Coward - to clarify, I only care about the ipv4 address, so I don't think I need 2 endpoints? Is there a way for a lambda function url to be only available via IPv4, in the same way as `api.whatismyip.com`?

Comment: You can put a security group on your lambda or put lambda behind an api gateway ([something like this](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-access)).

Comment: Do you have any control over the client that's invoking the Lambda function URL?

Comment: @rkochar - I know how to add a security group to an EC2 instance, but I don't see a Security Group option in the lambda "Configuration" screen. Am I missing something?

@jarmod - no. I don't have control over the client. It should work for an arbitrary client. I guess narrowing it down, I'm just trying to replicate `curl 'https://api.whatismyip.com/wimi.php' -X 'POST' -H 'origin: https://www.whatismyip.com' ` (which simply returns the ipv4 address of the client)

Comment: @maurera security groups are a feature of VPC. See this answer for more. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76184814/12555857

Comment: Thanks for the link @rkochar. I tried adding my lambda function to a VPC. I created a new security group called ipv4InboundOnly. I then tested the lambda function url twice. First test - no inbound rules on the security group, the function url was still accessible and the ipv6 address was returned. Second test - ipv4 inbound was added to the security group, and again the function url was accessible and the ipv6 address was returned.

Comment: @maurera are you sure you can curl the lambda in the VPC? A lambda inside a VPC usually loses access to the internet because VPC is a private network. You need something [like this, NAT or VPCE](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function) to get public internet access inside a VPC.

Comment: @rkochar - yes, I've just double checked. If I give the lambda a function url, I still successfully get a response from that url, from the outside even though the lambda is inside a vpc with no security group rules. I have not tested whether the lambda can receive inbound traffic from the public internet (which isn't required for my use case)

Comment: @maurera something is wrong here. In your lambda go to Configuration > VPC, do you see your VPC there? Did you make a new VPC or use an existing VPC?

Comment: @rkochar - yes, the vpc is there, in the lambda function's Configuration > VPC page. I did not make a new VPC. This is just the default VPC that was created when I created the AWS account

Comment: @maurera when you create a VPC you can choose to be ipv4 only. That should answer the question you asked in an earlier comment.

Comment: I made a default VPC and subnet with a hello world Lambda. It is only accessible when you explicitly ask for a function url. I would strongly advice against this because your url is sitting naked in public internet. I thought you were protecting your lambda with an API Gateway earlier. In any case, disabling ivp6 in the VPC (or in the lambda when putting lambda into VPC) will only allow ipv4.

Comment: There's a fair amount of misinformation in these comments. Security Groups aren't relevant during Lambda function invocation. You can't use Security Groups to restrict clients by IP address for requests via API Gateway to Lambda functions or for requests directly to Lambda function URLs. VPC networking configuration is irrelevant because Lambda function invocation (invocation specifically) happens in the AWS Lambda service control plane, outside of VPC networking.