# AWS NodeJS Lambda - Get Client IPV4 Address from Lambda Event Object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, clientip

I am trying to find the client IPV4 address in the Lambda Event Object.
*I am using Lambda function URL and lambda is **not** integrated with API Gateway.*

I managed to get it at 2 places -

1. event.requestContext.http.sourceIp
2. event.headers["x-forwarded-for"]

I make use of both these fields and if I find the IP address in any of the fields, I use it as client IP address (in case `x-forwarded-for` has multiple IPs, I use the first IP).

However, after deploying the lambda, I noticed that I am receiving the IP address as `2a02:c7c:e61d:8a00:7fd6:2525:b048:3089` which is in a different format that what I was expecting.

If I debug the same code using usual HTTP Server, I get the usual IPV4 address in HTTP Request.

I tried using node packages like `ipaddr.js` & `ipify` but none of them are solving my problem.

**Am I missing anything here?**
**Is there a way to convert the above IP address into IPV4 format?**

> PS - I found this free API `https://api.ipify.org/` which allows me to get the client IP on client side however it doesn't suit my requirements as I need to perform this on the server side.

Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: "in a different format that what I was expecting" it's IPv6.  "Is there a way to convert the above IP address into IPV4 format?" No. It's a newer version of IP that uses different addresses that do not correspond to IPv4 addresses.  If your client uses IPv6 to connect, that's what you're going to see on the server end.

Comment: @erik258 Thanks for the quick response! So if my client can be anyone who wants to connect to this API, I might get a mix of IPV4 / IPV6 IPs in the request?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to see client's ipv4 address from AWS Lambda Function URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77770785/how-to-see-clients-ipv4-address-from-aws-lambda-function-url)

Comment: Yes, you will get a mix of IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses. Why is the addressing scheme significant to your application?

Comment: @jarmod I need to manage a legacy application where the database column has a fixed character limit. Updating the database schema would fix the issue though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That sounds like the best approach. Anything else would be a challenge if you don't control DNS (which resolves the domain name to both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses) or the client (which may prefer IPv6, if available).